# push objects that equal true, into an array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, tile

I have an enemy hitting a bunch of tiles, and through a loop, I check all the tiles if the enemy is hitting them. I trace them and some will tell me if it's true or false. I want to be able to get the enemy to randomly choose from those that are true, and go on those tiles. It traces all the tiles that are in contact with the enemy, problem is, I'm not sure how I can get those tiles that are registering as true, into its own array, then have the enemy move randomly into those tiles.

```
 for (var j:int = 0; j < tileset.length; j++){
     trace(tileset[j].currentFrameLabel, tileset[j].hitTestObject(enemy));
     if (tileset[j].hitTestObject(enemy) && !tileset[j].hitTestObject(player)){
                 options.push(Boolean(true));
            }
```

---

EDIT: here's my timer function, where every 5 second, I want the enemy to move to an available  tile. Although you can't see tileset, it is an array that is equal to the movieclip that is a tile, which is in a for loop itself. So basically, tileset is 49 movie clips of tile. I have those available tiles pushed into another array which is options. Then I make a var called enemyPick which would be the counter. That's how far I am.

```
function timerenemy (event:TimerEvent) {

                    var options:Array = [];

                    for (var j:int = 0; j < tileset.length; j++){
                        if (tileset[j].hitTestObject(enemy) && ! tileset[j].tileMiddle.hitTestObject(player)) {
                            //trace(tileset[j].currentFrameLabel, tileset[j].hitTestObject(enemy));
                            tileset[j].outline.gotoAndStop("attack");
                            options.push(tileset[j]);
                        }

                        if (options.length > 0){
                            var enemyPick:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)

                        }

                    }
                    trace(enemyPick, options);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an array who's length is the maximum number of acceptable tiles.  For instance, in a straight line of tiles, only two can possibly be available at a time.  Now, each time you need to have the enemy move tiles, initialize a counter to 0.  Then, loop through each tile, and 'ask' if it is touching the enemy.  If it its, record it in array[counter], and increment counter.  After the loop, pick a random number from 0 to (counter) and use array[random number] as the tile that the enemy moves to.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I got everything up until connecting the counter to the actual tile. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: When you loop through each tile, simply refer to tileset[current_tile] instead of tileset[j].  When recording an acceptable tile, copy tileset[current_tile] (the actual tile) into okTiles[counter].  Then, you pick a random element from okTiles, and you can refer to that as you would a regular tile.  --EDIT--
Oh, I see this is actionscript, not Java.  The above might not work.  Instead, you can record current_tile (instead of tileset[current_tile]) into okTiles[counter].  And at the end, instead of referring to okTiles[rand_element], refer to tileset[okTiles[rand_element]].

Comment: Also, if you found my answer helpful, you can 'accept' it by clicking the green check (tick) next to it.

Comment: So to clarify, am I replacing tileset[j] with tileset[current_tile]? Would it help if I post the complete function I have this in?

Comment: Ah - That thing that sets the 'enemyPick' var (and the surrounding if statement) should be after the loop, since you don't want to pick which tile to move to until you've looped over all the tiles, so you know for sure that you have all the options.  Then, still inside the if statement, call whatever thing makes the enemy move with the destination 'options[enemyPick]'.